# Are there any alternatives to Hive "stored by" clause as Spark 2.0 does not support it?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

Spark 1.6 and below versions support HiveContext which supports Hive storage handler with "stored by" clause. However, Spark 2.0 does not support "stored by". So are there any alternatives for achieving Hive storage handler support in 2.0?

"reposting the question asked in databricks"

Comment: executing hql probably way https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html#hql(java.lang.String)